# Datetime objects not showing correct in bar plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, matplotlib

I tried to read something about this, and I think I maybe already have solved my issue, but then again, it does not work how I want it to work.

I have a list called `Year` with years from 1945 to 2014; it contains years like:

```
['1945', '1946', '1946', '1947', '1947', ...] # yes, some are the same.
```

I have converted these to `datetime` (using `datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y')`) so I can use them in my bar plot:

```
[datetime.datetime(1921, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1925, 1, 1, 0, 0), ...]
```

If I then plot my `datetime_year` as the x-axis, it should show the years from 1945 to 2014.

When I plot these and try to show the plot, there is nothing on the X axis at 1921 to 2014 which maybe should be?

Instead I got something out on 710000.

Code of my plot:

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

plt.bar(datetime_year, sorted_ratings2)
plt.suptitle('Ratings based on years', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Rating', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)  
plt.show()
```

And image of my plot: [image: http://i58.tinypic.com/mh4vok.png]

Comment: When i plot it, it does not show it correct

Comment: Well what does it do instead? It is not clear what your problem is. If you have 1921 in your list, why should it start at 1945?

Comment: unrelated: `datetime_years = [datetime(int(year), 1, 1) for year in Year]`

Comment: I have showed my code of how i plot, take a look.

Comment: Have a look at the [plot_date](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot_date#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date) function.

Comment: @user3618050: see, now we are getting somewhere. I've added a relevant tag for you; this is not my field but now at least people that do know this can find it.

Comment: It works if i convert my date to an float and not datetime? , then it will show correct values out for dates. Hmm

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as is:

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

Year = map(str, np.random.randint(1945, 2014, size=400)) # <-- put your data here
x = np.array([datetime(int(year), 1, 1) for year in Year]) 
y = np.random.random(x.shape) # <-- put your data here

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.suptitle('Ratings based on years', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Rating', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)  
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot]